# How to set up a Plot viewer for Wolfram Engine?

Tags: plotting, front-end, free-wolfram-engine

I would like to set up a plot viewer that can display plots from a Wolfram Engine session. (Something similar to python where when we plot something, the Graphic appears in a new window). The plot doesn't have to be interactive as the main idea is to quickly see what the plot looks like for the given code.

Of course, I can link the kernel with Jupyter notebooks and get an experience that closely resembles that of Mathematica notebooks, but I am curious to know if a plot viewer can be set up that can be directly invoked from the terminal.

I would really appreciate any tips and suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: What platform are you on and what is the name of your plot viewer?

Comment: I'm on macOS and the plot viewer is the one that cames with matplotlib in python

Comment: `SystemOpen[File["C:\\test.pdf"]]` runs the acrobat reader and opens this file on my machine. I am on Windows though. Try to see if you can `Export` a graphic to a certain location on disk. Then use the full path to the file and it should open with the registered application on your OS. This is as much as I can help you since I am not on a Mac. I am using Mathematica not the Wolfram Engine.

Comment: You may consider using Jupyter notebooks with wolfram engine. The plots get rasterised in Jypyter notebooks though. 

https://github.com/WolframResearch/WolframLanguageForJupyter

Comment: If viewing plots in PDF format, I would recommend [SumatraPDF](https://www.sumatrapdfreader.org/free-pdf-reader) instead of Acrobat Reader. The reason is that Sumatra is lighter, free and doesn't lock the file, so overwriting the file with a new version is easier. I say this as a user, I'm not linked to Sumatra development at all.

Comment: I would appreciate your feedback. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The basic idea is to set `$DisplayFunction` or `$Post`.

I have the following code in my tool bag:

```
BeginPackage["CommandLineUtilities`Display`"];

WolframPlayer;

Begin["`Private`"];

$TemporaryOutput = FileNameJoin@{$TemporaryDirectory, "WolframKernelOutput"};
If[!DirectoryQ@#, CreateDirectory@#] &@$TemporaryOutput;
WriteToShell[str_] := (
  If[Head@$ShellProcess =!= ProcessObject, $ShellProcess = StartProcess@$SystemShell];
  WriteLine[$ShellProcess, str];
  str
)

MakeNotebook[box_] := Notebook[{Cell@BoxData@box}, WindowSize -> All]

WolframPlayer[expr_, box_] := (
  $WolframPlayerProcess = If[# === {}, StartProcess@"WolframPlayer", None] &@SystemProcesses@"WolframPlayer";
  StringJoin[
    "WolframPlayer ",
    Export[FileNameJoin@{$TemporaryOutput, CreateUUID["CDFOutput-"]<>".cdf"}, MakeNotebook@box, "CDF"]
  ] //WriteToShell;
  ExportString[OutputForm@expr, "Text"]
)

$Epilog := (
  KillProcess/@{$ShellProcess, $WolframPlayerProcess};
  Quiet@DeleteFile@FileNames[__, $TemporaryOutput];
  If[FindFile["end`"] =!= $Failed, << "end`"] (* Original definition. You can read it with OwnValues. *)
)

End[];

EndPackage[];

(*$DisplayFunction = WolframPlayer[#, ToBoxes@#]&;*)
$Post = With[{box = ToBoxes@#},
  If[FreeQ[DynamicBox|DynamicModuleBox|GraphicsBox|Graphics3DBox]@box,
    #,
    WolframPlayer[#, box]
  ]
]&;
```

This calls `WolframPlayer`. For non-interactive contents, you can simply export as `PNG` and use another picture viewer.

Another way to do this is `` JavaGraphics` ``. It costs a lot of time on its first loading, so that it may be inconvenient when you frequently restart wolfram kernel sessions.

Answer (score 3):

There is a [complete solution](https://github.com/JerryI/wolfram-js-frontend), that uses Wolfram Engine and javascript as a frontend

[image]