# Mouse cursor disappears( Mathematica 13.1)

Tags: notebooks

I have been using Mathematica on Ubuntu for a while now. I have Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and MMA 13.1. I can't see the mouse cursor on the MMA notebook. I had the same problem with MMA 13.0. So, I updated it to MMA 13.1. I still have the same problem.

Comment: Support (support@wolfram.com) might be better qualified to help you with this (at least it's worth to write them)

Comment: I have lots of issues with mathematica 13.1 on endeavour os (arch linux). I mentioned an issue with scrolling on the touchpad (I use a mouse now) on a question (which almost got closed, this question might get closed). A user mentioned they are aware and gave a suggestion that did not work. I imagine the user works with wolfram and so I guess they know that 13.1 is not working well on linux. That said, as mentioned by the comment above, you should maybe report that error as they might not know that one.

Comment: If the cursor problem really bothers your work and you can't find any other solution at the moment, you could maybe consider using jupyter (but the cursor problem might related to your computer and so it might happen there too). I gave a list of options (and drawbacks) for using the wolfram language without using the mathematica notebook [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/274441/86543). It requires some work and you would have to set up an autosave system (i give a possibility I did not try yet in the answer provided).

Comment: The auto save or regular manual saving is needed because stopping an input or code cell from evaluating because it takes too long will require restarting the kernel and loosing unsaved calculations. Again, there are inconveniences and work involved so maybe that would be your last option if the cursor makes it hard to work (try python on jupyter first maybe to see if the cursor works like that before going through the process of getting a wolfram kernel to work on jupyter).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I have reached out mma support. Let's see how it goes.